# Parsing packet got error: unpack requires a string argument of length

Tags: python, structure, packet

I'm parsing a packet written in a binary file. I have to retrieve each field in different variables because I have to validate them. I have an error after using struct over some fields:

```
(pk_dst,)=struct.unpack('!I', line[16:20])#ip_dst struct.error: unpack
requires a string argument of length 4
```

I've search about this error but it seems is a unique problem in each case. I don't understand why the struct.unpack works perfectly with the IP address source (src), but not for the destination (dst) were I have the error.

My code is:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            mask1=0b1110000
            mask2=0b0001111
            ba = bytearray(line)
            byte=ba[0]
            frstb=byte & mask1 
            pk_ver=frstb >> 4 #ip_vr
            print 'Ver:',pk_ver
            pk_hl=byte & mask2 #ip_hl
            print 'HL:',pk_hl
            #packet= struct.unpack('BBHHHBBHLL140s', line)
            (pk_tos,)= struct.unpack('!B', line[1]) #ip_tos
            print 'TOS:',pk_tos
            (pk_len,)=struct.unpack('!H', line[2:4])#ip_len
            print 'LEN:',pk_len
            (pk_id,)= struct.unpack('!H', line[4:6])#ip_id
            print 'ID=',pk_id
            (pk_off,)= struct.unpack('!H', line[6:8])#ip_off
            print 'OFF:',pk_off
            (pk_ttl,)=struct.unpack('@B', line[8])#ip_ttl
            print 'TTL:',pk_ttl
            (pk_p,)=struct.unpack('@B', line[9])#ip_p
            print'PROT:',pk_p
            (pk_chsum,)=struct.unpack('!H', line[10:12])#ip_sum
            print'CHSUM:',pk_chsum
            (pk_src,)=struct.unpack('!I', line[12:16])#ip_src
            print'SRC:',pk_src
            (pk_dst,)=struct.unpack('!I', line[16:20])#ip_dst
```

The structure of the packet is in C language in a different code:

```
struct cip {
   uint8_t        ip_hl:4, /* both fields are 4 bits */
                  ip_v:4;
   uint8_t        ip_tos;
   uint16_t       ip_len;
   uint16_t       ip_id;
   uint16_t       ip_off;
   uint8_t        ip_ttl;
   uint8_t        ip_p;
   uint16_t       ip_sum;
   struct in_addr ip_src;
   struct in_addr ip_dst;
   char       head[100];
};
```

Hope someone can tell me what is wrong with my code.

This is the data that is in the packet (extract from the program that generated the packed), so you will see that the data is no bigger or smaller than 4 bytes.

```
HL:10 
Ver:4 
TOS:0 
Len:15360 
id:14082 
offset:64 
ttl:5 
Prot:6 
SUM:62141
src:167880896 
dst:184658112 
header:QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
```

---

Comment: No one can help me? I've tried everything... I think.

Comment: I know what is the problem! The line I'm reading is smaller than the amount of data I'm trying to unpack. Guess I'm not reading the whole data with readline()